# Convergence in total variation of a discrete measure to a density

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

In the following [exercise,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616036/show-that-%CE%A7-n-rightarrow-x-challenging-problem/3616358#3616358,) we proved that a discrete distribution can converge weakly to a density. Do you think we also have convergence in total variation:
$$\lim_n\sup_{K \in B(\mathbb{R})}|P_{X_n}(K)-P_X(K)|=0?$$

we can notice that $$|P_{X_n}(K)-P_X(K)|=|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\delta_n}1_K(\gamma_n+\left \lfloor{\frac{x-\gamma_n}{\delta_n}}\right \rfloor\delta_n)P(X_n=\gamma_n+\left \lfloor{\frac{x-\gamma_n}{\delta_n}}\right \rfloor\delta_n)dx-\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_K(x)f(x)dx|$$
Any suggestions?